# About centralizer of an infinite cyclic subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite cyclic subgroup of a group $G$.

Is the quotient group $G/C_G (H)$ of order two?

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Q}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $C_G(H)= G$.

Comment: Not necessarily. $G$ can be a lot bigger. What does happen is that $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ has order at most two. What made you think your claim would be true?

Comment: Also, have you checked out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619)? Your question is a bit lacking in context. Explaining why you ended up asking yourself this question is one way of adding some.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. I'll think about your comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: What you can say is that, if $H$ is a normal subgrop of $G$, then $G/C_G(H)$ has order $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is your statement true in general?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "true in general".What I meant was is that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is an infinite cyclic normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/C_G(H)$ has order $1$ or $2$. That is because the automorphism group of an infinite cyclic group has order $2$. In general, if $H$ is any normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not true. Any abelian group is a counterexample, since $C_G(H) = G$. However, we can find conditions on $H$ where this **becomes** true!

---

First, note that there is a homomorphism from $N_G(H)$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ by

$$g\mapsto (h\mapsto ghg^{-1})$$

that has kernel $C_G(H)$. **Since $H$ is infinite cyclic**, this means that $\operatorname{Aut}(H)\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Thus, the first isomorphism theorem tells us that $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ has order one or order two.

Now, let $G$ act on its set of subgroups by conjugation. The stabilizer of $H$ here is exactly $N_G(H)$, and the orbit of $H$, which we’ll denote $\mathcal{O}_H$, is the set of conjugate subgroups of $H$ in $G$. The orbit-stabilizer theorem says that the cosets of $N_G(H)$ are in bijection with $\mathcal{O}_H$.

Putting these two facts together, this means that the size of $G/C_G(H)$ is at most twice the size of $G/N_G(H)$ (which is equal to the size of $\mathcal{O}_H$). In order for the size of $G/C_G(H)$ to be $2$, there are two options. First, either

- $|\mathcal{O}_H|=1$, i.e. $H$ is normal
- $N_G(H) \ne C_G(H)$

or

- $|\mathcal{O}_H|=2$
- $N_G(H) = C_G(H)$.

Thus, the size of $G/C_G(H)$ is two if either of the above situations occur.